# Problem understanding a statement in Oxtoby's "Measure and Category", p.79. / Application of Zorn's lemma

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Assuming we already "know" that any set $E$ of positive outer measure contains a family of $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$ disjoint non-measurable sets. The statement I can't see is [2nd ed., p. 79]:

> "By Zorn's lemma, this family is contained in a maximal disjoint class
>   of non-measurable subsets of $E$. The complement of the union of such
>   a family must have measure zero. By adjoining it to one of the members of the family we obtain a descomposition of $E$ into $\mathfrak{c}$ disjoint non-measurable sets."

How exactly is Zorn's lemma applied? What are the chains and the upper bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partially ordered set is the set of all families of disjoint non-measurable sets containing the known family $F_0$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. The partial order is inclusion, the upper bounds are unions.

Formally, let

$$\mathfrak{M} = \left\lbrace F \subset \mathfrak{P}(E) : F \supset F_0,\, N \in F \Rightarrow N \text{ non-measurable},\, M,N \in F \Rightarrow M\cap N = \varnothing \right\rbrace,$$

and $F \leqslant G \iff F \subset G$.

It's easy to see that $\mathfrak{M}$ is inductively ordered, the upper bound of a chain $\mathfrak{C} \subset \mathfrak{M}$ is $C = \bigcup \mathfrak{C}$.